# How deploy in heroku codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku

I am trying to deploy my application in heroku with codeigniter, I have  a series of errors that I have been solving, but I would like to know the correct way to configure the framework codeigniter to be able to deploy it in heroku, the database is configured and I have no problems with your connection.

At this point I have problems with loading the helper.

Problem 1:
My helper located in the corresponding folder "helpers" 
 and its name is cargarConsultas_helper:

```
 <?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function getAreas()
{
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $query= $ci->db->get('areas');
    return $query->result();
}

?>
```

my controller in which I charge the helper:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();        
        $this->load->helper(array('url', 'cargarConsulta'));
 }
```

the error that throws me is:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyxAV.jpg)

I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rename your helper where the first letter only is upper case same applies for controllers and models and libraries etc

Filename Cargarconsultas_helper:

```
$this->load->helper(array('url', 'cargarconsulta'));
```

Class and filenaming guide

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: Thanks, it was not the solution but it helped me, I decided to change the name of the file "load query" for only "query", apparently have problem with compound names, please correct the answer to help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$this->loaa->helper('cargarConsultas')` error came because in your `filename` `cargarConsultas` in that `C` is capital and in helper you wrote `c` small so it unable to load that file